# Using Sortby and Echo together

Tags: sorting, command-line, command, echo

I have been trying to find a way to echo the values of a variable while their being sorted. Is there a way to do this without having to wait until all the values of that variable are already sorted? For example:

SORTBY (@FileName DESCENDING)

But I want to echo the value of each filename as it's being sorted. I was thinking of for or do loop but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Never seen this code used in a `batch-file`.  Are you sure you are writing a Windows .bat file?

Comment: yes command file.

Comment: There is no sortby command nor is that the syntax of the sort command. The built in sort command can be given the option to start sorting at a specific position only. You can read the help file by typing **sort /?** at the cmd prompt.

Comment: you know you're right. my bad. I'm interrogating someone else's code and that's a dbase query integrated with batch commands. it does write to a log file, so i'll guess I have to parse that. thank you.